# Java class list like in Python

Tags: java, python, class, list

I have classes which are inherited from abstract Packet( this class has abstract method named read which reads from ByteBuffer).

in Python i would do something like...

```
class Blabla(Packet):
    pass
class Blabla2(Packet):
    pass
```

and then i would init each class in list like this

```
_packets = [Blabla, Blabla2]
```

and when i would identify id of packet i would do like this

```
pck = _packets[packetId]()
```

Want to do the same in java. Is there any fast way(except using switch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do something very similar in Java.

You could have a list of [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) objects and then call `list.get(packetId).newInstance()` to create an instance of the correct class.

See the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29).

Answer (score 3):

This is what you should do:

```
ArrayList<Class> list = new ArrayList<Class>();
list.add(Class.forName("Blabla"));
list.add(Class.forName("Blabla2"));

list.get(packetId).newInstance();
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for `Class#newInstance()`.